# Is there a way to search all hex packages that depend on a certain package?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'd like to search for all hex packages that depend on comeonin, would that be possible?

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean through the web interface or command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hex.pm includes a section for the dependents of a package. If we look at the [comeonin](https://hex.pm/packages/comeonin) package, We can see that it currently has 41 dependant packages (right side) registered on hex.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer: No**

It would be possible, since all this information is freely available, but there aren't any existing tools that I know of that allow you do that.